# Tidyverse: This tidyselect interface doesn't support predicates yet

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am using R and exercising using the dslabs data for murders in the USA. As follows,

```
library(dslabs)
data("murders")
library(tidyverse)
murders <- mutate(murders, pop_in_millions = population / 10^6)`
murders <- mutate(murders, rate = total/population * 100000)`
murders <- mutate(murders, rank(-rate))`
select(murders, state, rank)
```

> Error: This tidyselect interface doesn't support predicates yet.
> i Contact the package author and suggest using `eval_select()`.
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Take a look at the language for expressing formatted text.

https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

It will help you learn how to craft a question that is legible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your last mutate call you forgot to create the `rank` variable. Therefore `select` can't find a column named `rank` in your dataset. The somewhat mysterious error message is related to the fact that `R` instead thinks you want to do something with the `rank` function. Try this:

```r
library(dslabs) 
data("murders") 
library(tidyverse) 
murders <- mutate(murders, pop_in_millions = population / 10^6) 
murders <- mutate(murders, rate = total/population * 100000) 
murders <- mutate(murders, rank = rank(-rate)) 
head(select(murders, state, rank))
#>        state rank
#> 1    Alabama   23
#> 2     Alaska   27
#> 3    Arizona   10
#> 4   Arkansas   17
#> 5 California   14
#> 6   Colorado   38
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>