# pivot_longer with tidyselect where, where but doesnt predicates?

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot, predicate, tidyselect

I am trying to use the `tidyselect` function `where` with `pivot_longer` and am getting the error that the `tidyselect` package doesn't support predicates.  That was seem somewhat unreasonable, so most likely I have a syntax error.  (I realize that SO is not for code debugging.)  I think it would help me understand better if someone could show me how to accomplish this task.

```
d <- dplyr::tribble(
  ~cups, ~glasses,
  "YES", "NO",
  "NO" , "YES",
  "YES", "NO",
  "YES", "NO",
  "NO" , "YES",
  "YES", "NO",
  "NO" , "YES",
  "NO" , "YES",
  "YES", "NO",
  "NO" , "YES",
  "YES", "NO",
  "NO" , "YES",
  "abc", "def"
) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number())
```

## This gives the result I want.

```
the_columns_I_want <- c('cups','glasses')
d %>% 
  pivot_longer(all_of(the_columns_I_want),values_to = 'result', names_to =  'group')
```

## But I want to select certain types of fields.

```
d %>% 
  pivot_longer(where(is.character),values_to = 'result', names_to =  'group')
```

## Show that it does work for `dplyr`, So I am not making this  mistake: ([Tidyverse: This tidyselect interface doesn't support predicates yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61022423/tidyverse-this-tidyselect-interface-doesnt-support-predicates-yet))

```
d %>% 
  select(where(is.character))
```

Answer (score 0):

With the `tidyr_1.1.0` and the devel version of `dplyr` it is working fine

```
library(tidyr)
d %>% 
  pivot_longer(where(is.character),values_to = 'result', names_to =  'group')    
# A tibble: 26 x 3
#      id group   result
#   <int> <chr>   <chr> 
# 1     1 cups    YES   
# 2     1 glasses NO    
# 3     2 cups    NO    
# 4     2 glasses YES   
# 5     3 cups    YES   
# 6     3 glasses NO    
# 7     4 cups    YES   
# 8     4 glasses NO    
# 9     5 cups    NO    
#10     5 glasses YES   
# … with 16 more rows
```

Comment: You still have `everything()` in the pivot_longer.  Note that my `select(where(is.character))` does the same thing as your `select_if`.   You are saying that I need two steps and can't do the selection in pivot_longer.  Also, you don't keep the `id` field.

Comment: @HarlanNelson not clear from your post because both the methods you showed is working fine for me

Comment: @HarlanNelson What is your package version of tidyr.  It is working fine for me with `where`

Comment: tidyr 1.0.2  does not work for me:  d %>% 
  pivot_longer(where(is.character),values_to = 'result', names_to =  'group')

Comment: @HarlanNelson that code is working for me.  Please check your package version of tidyr and dplyr

Comment: I need tidyr_1.1.0.  Thanks